# angularjs when to use promise and when to use Events

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using `angularjs` in my web application. To get the status of a method, which is going to take time to complete I want to use either promises or events.

I think I can use both in this scenario. With promise I can create a defer object and when wait for that object to resolve and with events I can raise the event when that action is completed and handle it on event handler.

I have tried both. But which one would be best?

Answer (score 0):

Use promise. You don't need bubbling/broadcasting mechanisms events provide.

Answer (score 0):

As by definition a `promise` is asynchronous event (action's eventual success value or failure).

So, you can use either one but in your situation i think `event` is good choice.